# Get the JavaScript variables from a HTML page in Ajax response

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, variables

I'm stuck with a problem you might resolve.
There is a HTML page with differents informations, in this page there is also some JS variables.

```
<div class="div1">
     <div class="div2"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var var1 = "Something";
var var2 = "Another thing";
var var3 = "";
</script>
```

Now when I call this page in ajax :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'mypage.php',
        success: function(data) {
                // Trying to get the var value
        }
});
```

I wish to get the var and what it contains. I can write this to get HTML part :

```
console.log($(data).find(".div1").html());
```

or

```
console.log($(data).find("script").html()); // To get the JS part
```

But I just want **only one var (like var2)**, not the whole javascript :/

I hope i'm clear, sorry for my english, I do my best.

Thank you

Comment: This may well be possible, but it would be a hacky solution to an issue simply caused by a bad design. Why do you need to get these variables? There is likely to be a better way, such as containing them in a 'settings' object within a separate .js file which can be included in both pages.

Comment: It's from a game, the page contains a unique "token", and I'm coding a plugin. But I need this token from this page, and I don't know how to get it

Comment: IS the site you're making the AJAX request to on the same domain as your page?

Comment: It's an userscript injected with Tampermonkey, so I guess, I don't know, maybe ?

Comment: So I think the easiest way solve it, it's add all your variables to hidden inputs and then get it from html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want the value of var2, right? If so, why not use Regex?

```
data.match(/var2 = "(.*)"/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value if you store the values in the form of [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) (JavaScript Object Notation)

i.e.,

```
<script>
{
var1: "Something",
var2: "Another Thing",
var3: "",
}
</script>
```

and at last,
`console.log($(data).find("script").html().var2);`
for the value of var2.

But, this is not the best way to do it!
You can either store all the variables and code in only one `<script>` tag or [use an external *.js file](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) which contains your code or use the browser [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to do it. Using cookies is also not recommended although it will work.

Comment: That could help, but I have no control on the called page, so I can't write the javascript part in JSON. I just can call the page and handle the response

Comment: I pushed in an array each line of the javascript part, so now I have something like :

0 : "var var1 = "Something";"
1: "var var2 = "Another Thing";

But there is maybe something better to do ?